# Will the university know I've submitted this assignment at my previous university?

Tags: plagiarism, self-plagiarism

I was studying at a university that shut down during Covid. I decided to move home and continue my studies with a different university. Some of my already completed units I got RPL for, some I did not. I have an assignment at my new university that is basically the same as an assignment I did at my previous university. If I submit this assignment to my new university, is there any way they will be able to tell that I've already used it before at a previous university?

Comment: “*I am considering committing academic misconduct. What are the chances that I will get caught?*” Why should we help you with such a question? The only reasonable answer is “Don’t commit misconduct.”

Answer (score 3):

If you submit exactly the same thing that will likely be considered self-plagiarism. If you still remember how to do it and solve it without resorting to the previous homework you will still be fine. In most cases going over previous notes (your own notes) will not constitute any honor code violation, but the only one that can tell you if that is ok or not is the instructor for that class, as that is not explicitly dealt with in any university's honor code.

All that aside, your intent clearly is to do something you think is wrong and not get caught, so it is clearly wrong and you know it.

Comment: When I was teaching, I always took the position, with respect to undergraduate summative assessments, that it's only self-plagiarism/misconduct if the student has previously _received credit(s) for_ the same work.  If OP's instructor takes the same position, it matters whether the assignment was from one of the units for which OP received RPL, or from one of the units for which they didn't.  But either way, you're right that it's important that OP discusses the situation with their instructor before going ahead.